# AutoMapper : Many to Many Relation mapping

Tags: c#, api, automapper

I have a relation between a `Student` to a `StudentSkill`, and then `StudentSkill` to `Skills`. I'm trying to create an API that will return students with a list of their skills that match up with the id.

In my database when I run this query it works fine...

```
select s.Name, sk.Name, sk.SkillId    
from Students s
join StudentSkills ss on ss.StudentId = s.StudentId
join Skills sk on sk.SkillId = ss.SkillId
```

[What The Query Returns.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4UTV.png)

Here are my classes:

```
[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
    public class Skill
    {
        [Key] // Denotes that this field will be used as the Key.
        // Tells the database to auto generate the next key with every new skill.
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int SkillId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Level { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<StudentSkill> Students { get; set; }
    }

    public class StudentSkill
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }

        public int SkillId { get; set; }
        public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Gender { Male,Female}
    [JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
    public class Student
    {
        [Key] // Denotes that this field will be used as the Key.
        // Tells the database to auto generate the next key with every new student.
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<StudentSkill> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping looks like this:

```
    public class StudentSkillProfile : Profile
    {
        public StudentSkillProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Student, StudentDto>()
                .ForMember(s => s.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.StudentId));

            CreateMap<Skill, SkillsDto>()
                .ForMember(s => s.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(source => source.SkillId));

            CreateMap<StudentSkill, SkillsDto>()
                   .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.SkillId));

            CreateMap<SkillsDto, StudentSkill>()
                  .ForMember(d => d.SkillId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id));
        }
    }
```

and finally my api method for returning a student is:

```
public Student GetStudent(int studentID, bool includeSkills)
{
    if (includeSkills)
    {
        return _context.Students
                       .Include(s => s.Skills)
                       .Where(s => s.StudentId == studentID)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    return _context.Students
                   .Where(s => s.StudentId == studentID)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The context and modelBuilder method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StudentSkill>().HasData(
            new StudentSkill() { SkillId = 1, StudentId = 1},
            new StudentSkill() { SkillId = 2, StudentId = 1},
            new StudentSkill() { SkillId = 3, StudentId = 1},
            new StudentSkill() { SkillId = 1, StudentId = 2},
            new StudentSkill() { SkillId = 3, StudentId = 2}
        );

modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasData(
        new Student(){Name = "Joe", StudentId = 1, Age = 10, Gender = Gender.Male},
        new Student(){Name = "Jen", StudentId = 2, Age = 10, Gender = Gender.Female}
    );

modelBuilder.Entity<StudentSkill>()
            .HasKey(ss => new { ss.StudentId, ss.SkillId });

modelBuilder.Entity<StudentSkill>()
            .HasOne(ss => ss.Skill)
            .WithMany(sk => sk.Students)
            .HasForeignKey(ss => ss.SkillId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Student
            .HasOne(st => st.Student)
            .WithMany(sk => sk.Skills)
            .HasForeignKey(st => st.StudentId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Skill>().HasData(
        new Skill(){ SkillId = 1, Name = "Forward Roll", Level = "Beginner", },
        new Skill(){ SkillId = 2, Name = "Backward Roll", Level = "Beginner" },
        new Skill(){ SkillId = 3, Name = "CartWheel", Level = "Beginner" }
```

This is what I get when I run it through Postman:

[I'm expecting a name and level (from Skills with the matching ID) in place of those nulls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayut7.png)

I'm still fairly new to programming and C# so a lot of it is just me trying a bunch of things and reading loads of docs. Any help would be appreciated. The Github for this project is [Here, in the NoClue Branch haha](https://github.com/Kayrim/Gymnastics.git)

Comment: You forgot to mention what is happening ... are you getting an error, are you getting data that you expect to look different? What do you expect it to look like, etc. That's minor and someone can probably help with what you have but by putting that in, experienced people can likely jump straight to the exact spot in your code that needs a tweak. Make it as easy for them to help you as you can. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I Knew I forgot something o_O 
I've added a screenshot of what I get on Postman when I run the HttpGet.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html